# How to drop elements of a list which are not satisfying a certain condition?

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I am trying to formalize route descriptions in haskell for a spatial reasoning simulation. In the process I need a function to drop some elements in a list like this which does not satisfy a condition:

```
 [(["Keyhan","ave."],["Keyhan4","alley"]),(["13","number"],["Keyhan","ave."]),(["13","number"],["Keyhan4","alley"])]
```

I want all the pairs in this list which contain `"number"` and anything, except for `"number"` and `"alley"` to be removed from the list. Here for example the desired answer is:

```
[(["Keyhan","ave."],["Keyhan4","alley"]),(["13","number"],["Keyhan4","alley"])]
```

which means the pair containing `"ave."` and `"number"` `(["13","number"],["Keyhan","ave."])` is removed.

I am confused and I really don't know how to write this function. Precisely I don't know how to formalize the condition. I would truly appreciate your help!

Comment: i think you already used the name of that function in the tags - `filter` it keeps all elements that satisfy a given condition

Comment: i think your difficulty is rather to formalize the datamodel - you have a list of tupels of two list of Strings, and the condition on top of that data model - try to come up with a good datatype and then think about the condition/filter again. I'll bet it will be easier then.

Comment: Thanks, I know that this data structure is not the best, but the problem is that now I am in the middle of a project done partially by someone else and any change in this level will change many other things! That's why I was wondering if there is a way for filtering the list with the same structure as it already has...

Comment: You can of course work directly with the strings: `filter (\([x,y],[a,b]) -> (y=="number" && b=="alley") || y /= "number")`. Note this makes a lot of implicit assumptions that will give nasty errors if violated. If the function is any bigger than this, then defining your own datatype will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

the only answer I can get from your description is

```
condition (x,y) = let xy = if any (== "number") x
                             then any (`elem` ["number","alley"]) y
                             else True
                      yx = if any (== "number") y
                             then any (`elem` ["number","alley"]) x
                             else True
                   in xy && yx
```

it is dirty and could be refactored easily but i don't have time right now for prettyfying